# Why doesn't the limit $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{ e^{x+y} - x - y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Why is this limit non-existant?

$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{ e^{x+y} - x - y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$

I can't seem to find $2$ different paths that would show it is non-existant.

Comment: In $[-\infty,+\infty]$, the limit is $+\infty$. The limit doesn't exist in $\mathbb{R}$ because $+\infty \notin \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But you're going to *"divide by zero"*.

Comment: Can you name a path along which there _is_ a limit? Can you prove it?

Answer (score 2):

Along $y = -x$ for example:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{ e^{x+y} - x - y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{|x|}} \rightarrow \infty$$

Answer (score 1):

A change to polar coordinates will suffice:
$$
\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{ e^{r(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)} - r(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)}{r}=\lim_{r\to 0}[\frac{ e^{r(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)}}{r} - (\sin\theta+\cos\theta)]
$$
Which does not exist since $\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{ e^{r(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)}}{r}$ does not exist for any $\theta$.

Comment: How do you get your second equality?  It looks like you're assigning a value to $\lim_{r\to0}e^{kr}/r$...

Answer (score 0):

The limit of the numerator is $1$. The limit of the denominator is $0$. Are you sure that your numerator isn't supposed to be $e^{x+y}-x-y-1$? That would be more interesting.

Comment: This should probably be a comment on the original question.